# Extraccion de texto en rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Buen día,

Tengo el siguiente problema tengo una lista con los siguientes códigos:

```
O-Cobrador
700700001
8060000
8060000
806000010
806000010
806000010
9007004
9007004
702900010
9007004
901007029
901007029
90107029
901008060
901007012
901007012
90107039
901007039
901007039
```

De esta lista O-Cobrador se debe extraer cierto números, anexo la lista:

```
> CODIGO
7006
7007
7009
7012
7017
7029
7039
7070
8029
8030
8031
8032
7003
7004
7005
7038
7104
8050
7015
7032
7038
7083
8050
8060
```

Soy nuevo en R y traigo pensamiento de formulas de excel, lo que realice fue lo siguiente:

```
BasePeS <- BasePeS %>% mutate(Codi = ifelse(nchar(BasePeS$`O-COBRADOR`)==8, substr(BasePeS$`O-COBRADOR`,1,4),
                                        ifelse(nchar(BasePeS$`O-COBRADOR`)==9, substr(BasePeS$`O-COBRADOR`,6,9),"Sin Cobrador")))
```

Con este código logre sacar algunos códigos de acuerdo al largo de la cadena, pero hay cadenas donde pueden ser más largas o los códigos se encuentran en medio, quisiera saber si existe alguna formula para extraer los codigos que existan en O-Cobrador con base a la lista "Codigos"
#############################################################################

@patriciomoracho

Estos son los ejemplos, la primer secuencia donde el largo es de 8 dígitos y los últimos siempre es 0001 es la siguiente:

70060001
70070001
70090001
70120001
70290001
70700001
80600001

De aqui los cobradores son:

7006
7007
7009
7012
7029
7070
8060

La segunda secuencia es de 9 caracteres donde los primeros 5 corresponden a usuarios que ingresaron la información de forma "manual" en el sistema y los cuales no son de relevancia, anexo ejemplos

901000990 este tipo de cadena en especifico no contiene ningún organismo cobrador, esto sucede por el usuario que lo registro no identifico al cobrador

Los siguientes si tienen cobrador

901007003
901007004
901007038
901007294
901008050
901017003
901017004
901017005
901018050

En estos ejemplos el cobrador se encuentran en las ultimas 4 posiciones:

7003
7004
7038
7294
8050
7003
7004
7005
8050

La ultima secuencia el sistema de igual manera contiene 9 dígitos la estructura es similar a la de la primer secuencia pero por error el sistema agrega un 0, el cobrador se encuentra en los primeros 4 digitos.

Anexo ejemplos:

701200010
701200010
702900010
702900010

Los cobradores son:

7012
7012
7029
7029

Estas son las únicas formas que aparecen los cobradores, no aparecen en medio (Perdón por la confusión)

Comment: Revisemos el cobrador 7029, ¿debemos considerar que está en  702900010 y en 901007029 y 90107029? ¿y que pasaría con una cadena como 901007029 si 9010 también es un cobrador válido? Creo que deberías empezar explicando como es el formato de  O-Cobrador, que patrones pueden existir y tal vez con eso podamos darte una respuesta que cubra todos los casos

Comment: @PatricioMoracho No se pueden mezclar 2 organismos cobradores, los demás dígitos corresponden a usuarios o cadenas del sistema, el cobrador puede estar al principio o al final, pero nunca van aparecer 2 al mismo tiempo

Comment: No, no digo que haya dos cobradores, digo, como ejemplo, que pasaría si hubiera un patrón numérico que sea otro dato y de casualidad coincide con un cobrador. Mencionas en tu pregunta que este dato puede aparecer a derecha, a izquierda o en el medio, ¿Cómo podemos saber cual es el caso? 9007004, el cobrador es el 9007 o 7004? ¿Como sabríamos que hay que mirar el de la derecha o el de la izquierda?  Sin entender bien que contiene y cuales son los patrones posibles para `O-Cobrador` me cuesta pensar una solución que resuelva  todas las posibles combinaciones que pudiera haber.

Comment: De acuerdo, no es posible identificar el código sin saber muy en detalle como se conforma `O-Cobrador` y sobre todo como se generan el resto de los dígitos que no son el código. Extraer por posiciones en la cadena sería más seguro si en la base de datos hubiera otra columna que te da información certera sobre esa conformación. Digamos, tienes una columna que te indica el provedor de datos y sabes que el provedor de datos A siempre pone el código a la izquierda, que B lo pone al final, etc. De lo contrario hay una ambigüedad inevitable.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho la extracción puede arrojar 3 tipos de variables, la primera es con un largo de texto de 8 dígitos donde los primeros 4 contienen el cobrador, los siguientes 4 dígitos los asigna el sistema, re agrego ejemplos en la misma pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que esta es una alternativa que funciona, pero podría fallar en ciertas condiciones. Al final hay una advertencia.

Recreo las estructuras de datos.

```
codigo <- structure(list(CODIGO = c("7006", "7007", "7009", "7012", "7017", 
"7029", "7039", "7070", "8029", "8030", "8031", "8032", "7003", 
"7004", "7005", "7038", "7104", "8050", "7015", "7032", "7038", 
"7083", "8050", "8060")), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")

BasePeS <- structure(list(O.Cobrador = c("700700001", "8060000", "8060000", 
"806000010", "806000010", "806000010", "9007004", "9007004", 
"702900010", "9007004", "901007029", "901007029", "90107029", 
"901008060", "901007012", "901007012", "90107039", "901007039", 
"901007039")), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = "data.frame")
```

Si lo que necesitas es asociar a cada fila de `BasePeS` con un código de cobrador podrías hacer un join por regex. ¿Qué es eso? Un join, de forma muy simple, es una unión entre dos data.frame en el que se empatan filas que tienen algo en común y se agregan las columnas. Un regex es una expresión regular, que en este caso te permite que haya "algo en común" aún si no coincide toda la cadena de caracteres, es decir, aún si coinciden solo parcialmente. Con regex se pueden hacer muchísimas otras cosas, pero por ahora interesa esta.

Esta sería la solución:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
regex_left_join(BasePeS, codigo, by = c(O.Cobrador = "CODIGO"))
```

y obtener

```
   O.Cobrador CODIGO
1   700700001   7007
2     8060000   8060
3     8060000   8060
4   806000010   8060
5   806000010   8060
6   806000010   8060
7     9007004   7004
8     9007004   7004
9   702900010   7029
10    9007004   7004
11  901007029   7029
12  901007029   7029
13   90107029   7029
14  901008060   8060
15  901007012   7012
16  901007012   7012
17   90107039   7039
18  901007039   7039
19  901007039   7039
```

¿Cómo funciona? `regex_left_join()` hace un match por regex entre las columnas de `codigo` y `BasePeS`, si en `O.Cobrador` encuentra como subcadena alguna de las cadenas que están en `CODIGO` hace match y agrega en la columna `CODIGO` del resultado el valor de `CODIGO` que encontró. Como es `left_join` va a conservar todas filas del data.frame "a la izquierda", en este caso `BasePeS`, en las filas que no hay coincidencia pondrá `NA`.

Te ahorras el trabajo engorroso y riesgos se extraer por posiciones y armar condicionales largo/posición.

## ADVERTENCIA:

Si por azar o algo sistemático el resto de las cadena `O.Cobrador` (la parte que no debería ser un código de cobrador) llega a ser también un código válido en `CODIGO` tendrás un falso match. No es recomendable esta aproximación si tu código se va a ejecutar sin supervisión y validación humana. Ahora, si es para un análisis puntual y desarrollas una buena estrategia de validación (por ejemplo, saber que no puedes tener valores duplicados en `O.Cobrador` después de hacer el join) entonces podría funcionar.

La aproximación extrayendo subcadenas por posición también podría ser riesgosa, sobre todo si no puedes saber de antemano los largos en cada caso o haya registros en los que el largo va creciendo. En cualquiera de los casos: conocer muy bien que es y como se compone `O.Cobrador` y validar, validar, validar.

Quizás alguien más con formación más sólida en programación pueda darte una alternativa más segura. Se me hace un problema frecuente de los que tienen soluciones probadas y la gente del rubro las conoce.

Comment: realice el vector "codigo" corri la función (anexo arriba) pero me duplico todos los registros que tenia a la izquierda

Comment: ya vi por que arrojo error, quite el mute y solo deje BasePeS <- regex_left_join(BasePeS, BaseCObrador, by = c(`O-COBRADOR` = "O.COBRADOR"))
y no hubo error, al ver tus notas veo que puede dar falso Match, hay forma de hacer alguna validación para ver si no dio un falso match?

Comment: No creo que haya una forma de validarlo, depende mucho de como se conforman los datos de `O-COBRADOR`. @Patricio Moracho hizo algunos comentarios a tu pregunta te podrían ayudar mucho a pensar el problema. Como estrategia general podrías generar intencionalmente datos similares a los de `O-COBRADOR`  en los que sabes que va a haber una falso match para ver como falla la función y aprender desde ahí. También estimar sobre cuantas filas deberías tener como resultado del join y ver si eso coincide con lo que obtienes. Suerte!